# Function not being executed. Scroll Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, function, getboundingclientrect

So, in my HTML I've got a class called .myFeature_info, along with that I've included the following script at the end of the `<body>` tag.

I'm wondering why the function is not being called while I am scrolling.

Here's the code, I'd love to know the 'why', I'd love to use JS only.

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    function isInViewPort (){
    var myFeature_info = document.getElementsByClassName('myFeature_info')[0];
    var getPos = myFeature_info.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(getPos);
  }
});
```

Comment: you're declaring the function but you don't invoke it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling any function on scroll but defining a function! Separate the definition and call it as you scroll:

```
function isInViewPort (){
var myFeature_info = document.getElementsByClassName('myFeature_info')[0];
var getPos = myFeature_info.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(getPos);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
 isInViewPort()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT. I can't believe I didn't catch that. I guess I should take a little break, lol. Thanks, again.

Comment: Or, forget about the function name and just put the function body (from `var myFeature_info`, etc) in the event listener.